# Security Exception for accessing wifi

Tags: java, android

Actually I am trying to check network connection in background through receiver.
Coding and all is ok. but showing permission issue.
Please try to help me.

Below is my code.

NetworkChangeReceiver:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

{

```
public static final String NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION = "com.onnurinet.NetworkAvailable";
public static final String IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE = "isNetworkAvailable";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
        if (isOnline(context)) {
           // dialog(true,context);
            Toast.makeText(context,"connection is there",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("TAG", "Online Connect Intenet ");
        } else {
            //dialog(false,context);
            Log.e("TAG", "Conectivity Failure !!! ");
            Toast.makeText(context,"Could not Connect to internet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    try {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        //should check null because in airplane mode it will be null
        return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

BroadcastEvent class:

```
public class BroadcastEvent extends Activity {

Boolean networkStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /*int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(BroadcastEvent.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);*/
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(NetworkChangeReceiver.NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean isNetworkAvailable = intent.getBooleanExtra(IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE, false);
             networkStatus = Boolean.valueOf(isNetworkAvailable ? "connected" : "disconnected");
            if(networkStatus){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Network Status: " + networkStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Network Status: " + networkStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Network Status: " + networkStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_main), "Network Status: " + networkStatus, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, intentFilter);

}
```

}

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

//------------------------------STBService---------------------------------------
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />


<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/airstream_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeMainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />


    <activity
        android:name=".BroadcastEvent"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.onnurinet.receivers.NetworkChangeReceiver">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Please try to check my code and tell where I have done mistake. I clean the project and check in google but still I am not getting the issue.

Error:

```
10-24 15:13:16.601 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10405 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
```

10-24 15:13:16.601 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
10-24 15:13:16.601 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
10-24 15:13:16.601 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:964)
10-24 15:13:16.601 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:610)
10-24 15:13:16.601 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at com.onnurinet.receivers.NetworkChangeReceiver.isOnline(NetworkChangeReceiver.java:41)
10-24 15:13:16.601 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at com.onnurinet.receivers.NetworkChangeReceiver.onReceive(NetworkChangeReceiver.java:23)
10-24 15:13:16.601 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2642)
10-24 15:13:16.601 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:154)
10-24 15:13:16.601 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
10-24 15:13:16.602 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-24 15:13:16.602 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-24 15:13:16.602 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
10-24 15:13:16.602 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-24 15:13:16.602 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-24 15:13:16.602 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
10-24 15:13:16.602 19293-19293/com.onnet.airstream W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)

Comment: What is the error??

Comment: Share your stacktrace on the question.

Comment: please find my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Code

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET" />
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement run time permission

[read this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.

If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.

Note: Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users can revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a lower API level. You should test your app to verify that it behaves properly when it's missing a needed permission, regardless of what API level your app targets.

Comment: where I should give permission in receiver or in activity file?

Comment: In your main activity,before accessing wifi state

Comment: for testing purpose, you can enable permission by going to settings -> Apps -> [your app name]->permission

Comment: Replace <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />    TO   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 0):

If you running (support) on Android 6.0 or above (API Level >= 23), then need to implement [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)